# Google app engine disable external IP addresses

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine

I have a question concerning Google app Engine yaml files and Quotas.
For a new client of ours we are setting up a new app in Frankfurt (Europe-west-3) and started using app engine there.

Immediately we noticed that only 8 IP addresses are allowed in Europe-west-3 and an increase in quota is rarely allowed since they have a shortage.

That forced me to move the application temporarily to Belgium (europe-west-1).
Is there any way I can disable assigning external IP addresses to my current instances? or do I need another resource to allow this.

Current yaml file:

```
runtime: custom
env: flex
service: XXXXXXXXx
threadsafe: true
automatic_scaling:
  min_num_instances: 2
  max_num_instances: 20
  cpu_utilization:
    target_utilization: 0.5
network:
  name: default
  instance_tag: XXXXXXXXx
env_variables:
  CLIENT: XXXXXXXXx
  NODE_ENV: production
```

While the environment does work and my docker images are being created, I face the limits of this Quota.
Simply disabling it, since I don't use their debugger would help me, yet I have not found any documentation on how to achieve this.

This is the error I get when I am running out of IP addresses (This is step 4 in my cloud builds).

```
Step #4 - "Deploy": ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) INVALID_ARGUMENT: The following quotas were exceeded: IN_USE_ADDRESSES (quota: 8, used: 8 + needed: 2).
Step #4 - "Deploy": WARNING: Deployment of service [frontend] will ignore the skip_files field in the configuration file, because the image has already been built.
```

Thanks a lot for all the advice in advance :)

Comment: Are you sure you are using Google App Engine, and not some other service? GAE does not assign specific IP addresses to your project; they are all shared. Show us exactly what you saw and where you saw it.

Comment: I added the error I am receiving while deploying to app engine.
The IP addresses are shown on the instances tab of Google App Engine under the label VM IP.

Comment: Are you deleting old versions of your app?

Comment: I am after the build was succesfull and the old version can be removed since traffic is being sent to the new one. All older versions of my App engine apps are also on 0 instances, so shouldn't be taken into account.

Comment: I can't make any sense of that error, then. Is that the only thing of possible interest logged?

Comment: I receive the error while executing this command: gcloud app geploy --image-url:gcr.io/xxx/yyyy:zzzz
This works, if I do all parts of the application one by one. Yet while doing multiple at once or while more instances are required by the load on the application. It is not possible to complete builds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

App Engine external IP is [allocated dynamically](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/kb/) and it is not possible to configure/disable it during deployment in the app.yaml file.

However, there is open [Public Feature Request to add this functionality](https://issuetracker.google.com/130707094)

This message: "The following quotas were exceeded: IN_USE_ADDRESSES" 
means, that you have reached IP quota limit defined in your project.

Current quota limit for IP can be found in the Console:

> Google Cloud Console > IAM & Admin > Quotas > Metrics > In-use IP addresses

Check the [documentation, how to increase the quota](https://cloud.google.com/compute/quotas) if needed.

Comment: Thanks for answering this question, yet the problem is that a quota increase is never allowed in the specified reason (europe-west-3, Frankfurt, Germany). The requests for quota I did in europe-west-1 and europe-west-4 did always work and were accepted rather fast.
Thus the most practical solution seemed to disable their external IP addresses all together since they seem rather useless(even if that would lose me the debug option)

Comment: Since disabling external IP for App Engine is not currently possible, I did create for you Public Feature Request, that you will find under this link: https://issuetracker.google.com/130707094
If you star it, you will be notified on any changes on its status.

Comment: Thank you so much for creating this, I will enable notifications and follow this up closely since I am afraid this will happen in more regions then only europe-west-3.

Comment: Hello @mitchken, it looks like the [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/130707094) is still in progress. 
Please consider [accepting](https://serverfault.com/help/accepted-answer) and upvoting the answer above as it seems like it was helpful. Thanks